# What does "the second term" mean? Please help me out.

Tags: numerical-methods

Question : Assume we have a sample of 4 data points: 1=1, 2=3, 3=2, 4=2. We want to use the formula Σ(−̅)^2/( −1), [Σ=1 → n] of sample variance for this dataset. What is the numerical value of the second term in the sum in the numerator of the formula?

I am confused with the concept of "1st, 2nd term"
What does this mean? and what is the answer for the question?

Thanks a lot in advance!

[Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqmVt.png)

Comment: The first term equals $\dfrac{(X_1 - \overline X)^2}{n - 1} $, the second term equals  $\dfrac{(X_2 - \overline X)^2}{n - 1} $...

Comment: I would recommend using MathJax in order to format your formulas better

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Answer (score -1):

In $\sum_{i= 1}^\infty a_i= a_1+ a_2+ a_3+ \cdot\cdot\cdot$ the "first term" is $a_1$ and the "second term" is $a_2$.